# Unexpected '\d' in JSLint

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

Just a small question:
I'm trying to make my code JSLint errorfree, but ran into this problem:

Unexpected '\d'. (in both of the regex's)

```
hourduration = parseInt(activity.endTime.replace(":\d\d", ""), 10) - parseInt(activity.startTime.replace(":00", ""), 10);

minuteduration = (parseInt(activity.endTime.replace("(\d)?\d:", ""), 10) - parseInt(activity.startTime.replace(":00", ""), 10)) / 60;
```

What can I do to improve my regex so that jslint will validate it?

Thanks!

Solution:

```
hourduration = parseInt(activity.endTime.replace(/:\d\d/, ""), 10) - parseInt(activity.startTime.replace(":00", ""), 10);

minuteduration = (parseInt(activity.endTime.replace(/(\d)?\d:/, ""), 10) - parseInt(activity.startTime.replace(":00", ""), 10)) / 60;
```

Comment: I doubt you regexp validity. And even if it does, It is replaced by empty string which cannot be converted to any integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLint wants you to use a RegExp object or a `/regex/` 'string', not a normal string:

```
// JSLint error
foo.match(':\d\d');
foo.match(RegExp(':\\d\\d'));

// no error
foo.match(/:\d\d/);
foo.match(new RegExp(':\\d\\d'));
```

EDIT: All examples are valid, but the last 2 are the official way of working with regexes.